# de Rham type cohomology for covariant derivative?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

We know that in general for a covariant derivative $D$ on a vector bundle $\xi$ over $M$ we don't have $D \circ D = 0$.  This prevents us from having the following cochain complex
\begin{equation}
   \Omega^0(M;\xi) \xrightarrow{\hspace{.2cm}D\hspace{.2cm}} \Omega^1(M;\xi) \xrightarrow{\hspace{.2cm}D\hspace{.2cm}} \Omega^2(M;\xi) \xrightarrow{\hspace{.2cm}D\hspace{.2cm}} \cdots
\end{equation}
thus we cannot in general define a de Rham cohomology for covariant derivatives.

My question is, is there any special case in which we can define a de Rham cohomology for covariant derivatives?  Is the special case interesting?

Thank you very much for your attention!

PS: as is pointed out in the comment we can define de Rham cohomology based on covariant derivatives for flat vector bundle.  So I should refine my question to be: is there any special case other than flat vector bundle?  What is the common feature shared by such vector bundles and what is the consequence of such feature(s)?

Comment: Yes and the special case is when the covariant derivative is _flat_ ($D\circ D = 0$). This was discussed at some length in a [previous question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/6618/2622).

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot for pointing that out, Igor!  But is there any other special case?  Flat vector bundle is not very interesting apparently.

Comment: I do not agree that the flat case is uninteresting. The cohomology of the de Rham complex of a flat connection $D$ has interesting things to say about the local structure of the moduli space of flat connections near $D$, which is of some interest. This is a simple case of the story told in Igor's link.

Comment: @Mike: I see. Thanks for pointing out that link with moduli space!